# Not able to set audit object access in Local Security Policy using c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unmanaged, local-security-authority

I'm using the following code to enable audit object access for success, failure in Local security policy.

```
bool EnableObjectAccessPolicy()
{
    NTSTATUS ntsResult;
    LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle = GetPolicyHandle();
    DebugLogMessage("\n%x",PolicyHandle);
    PPOLICY_AUDIT_EVENTS_INFO ppPAUDInfo = NULL;

    ntsResult = LsaQueryInformationPolicy(PolicyHandle,PolicyAuditEventsInformation,(PVOID *)&ppPAUDInfo);
    DebugLogMessage("\n-----%x",ntsResult);
    if(ntsResult != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        DebugLogMessage("LsaSetInformationPolicy returned %lu\n ntstatus %04x",LsaNtStatusToWinError(ntsResult),ntsResult);
        LsaFreeMemory(PolicyHandle);
        return FALSE;
    }
    DebugLogMessage("\nMaxCount is %d",ppPAUDInfo->MaximumAuditEventCount);
    DebugLogMessage("\nEventAuditingOptions at 0 is %d",ppPAUDInfo->EventAuditingOptions[0]);
    if(ppPAUDInfo->EventAuditingOptions[2] != 3)
    {
        DebugLogMessage("\nNot equal to 3");
        ppPAUDInfo->EventAuditingOptions[2] = 3;
        ntsResult = LsaSetInformationPolicy(PolicyHandle,PolicyAuditEventsInformation,ppPAUDInfo);
        printf("ntstatus is %04x",ntsResult);
        if(ntsResult != STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            DebugLogMessage("LsaSetInformationPolicy returned %lu\n ntstatus %04x",LsaNtStatusToWinError(ntsResult),ntsResult);
            LsaFreeMemory(PolicyHandle);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    LsaClose(PolicyHandle);
    return TRUE;
}

LSA_HANDLE GetPolicyHandle()
{

  LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes;
  NTSTATUS ntsResult;
  LSA_HANDLE lsahPolicyHandle;

  // Object attributes are reserved, so initialize to zeros.
  ZeroMemory(&ObjectAttributes, sizeof(ObjectAttributes));

  // Get a handle to the Policy object.
  ntsResult = LsaOpenPolicy(
        NULL,    //Name of the target system.  &lusSystemName,
        &ObjectAttributes, //Object attributes.
        POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION | GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_EXECUTE | POLICY_ALL_ACCESS, //Desired access permissions.
        &lsahPolicyHandle  //Receives the policy handle.
    );
    DebugLogMessage("\nOpenPolicy returned %x\n",LsaNtStatusToWinError(ntsResult));

  if (ntsResult != STATUS_SUCCESS)
  {
    // An error occurred. Display it as a win32 error code.
    DebugLogMessage("\nOpenPolicy returned %lu\n",LsaNtStatusToWinError(ntsResult));
    return NULL;
  } 
  DebugLogMessage("Policy Handle is \n%x",lsahPolicyHandle);

  return lsahPolicyHandle;
}
```

the above code works perfectly when i make standalone exe and test. But as soon as i integrate the above code with my main project `ppPAUDInfo->MaximumAuditEventCount` gives a six digit count which should be 9. And my main project process quits as soon as i try to access `ppPAUDInfo->EventAuditingOptions[index]`.

Comment: Which error code does your debug messages output?

Comment: their is no error code coming.LsaQueryInformationPolicy is not filling the ppPAUDInfo structure members correctly without generating any error.ppPAUDInfo->MaximumAuditEventCount is coming as a garbage value .But at the same time the standalone exe works perfectly fine.

Comment: Except for the fact that you should release the returned `POLICY_AUDIT_EVENTS_INFO` structure, I can confirm that your code works as a standalone exe. Can you then provide some more information on your main project? Did you create a DLL from the code above?